# How to emit Windows line endings when writing element strings from XML source to plain text files in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, newline, xmlreader

I have a PowerShell script that reads very large XML files and extracts the text values of certain elements which represent embedded C# code. The script then saves the element texts into .cs code files in a directory structure which matches the structure of the XML file. For performance, I'm using XmlReader since the files are so large (sometimes >200 MB).

The original XML file has Windows line endings (CRLF) but the .NET Framework XmlReader class "normalises" the line endings from CRLF to just LF (in line with XML specifications) when it reads from the file.

My question is: how can I force PowerShell to restore the line endings to Windows standard when it writes out the file out to disk, so I don't get source control "noise" resulting from changes in line endings?

I'm currently writing the files by using the following PowerShell statement: `New-Item -Path $path -Force -ItemType file -Value $reader.ReadElementString()`

The `$reader` variable is an instance of `[System.Xml.XmlReader]`.

Comment: What if you try to do something like ``$reader.ReadElementString().Replace("`n","`r`n")`` ?

Comment: How are you writing the XML document to the file? (If you use the defaults you should get `\r\n`: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars)).

Comment: The XML file is pre-existing and has CRLF line endings. My objective is to extract the text contents of some elements and save them into non-XML files, which I do using the statement shown above. I don't write any XML output at all. The plain text files I'm writing are getting LF line ends instead of the desired CRLF.

Comment: @zespri, please consider entering your comment as a proposed solution. It's very simple, and it's what I've ended up using, so I will accept it if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$reader.ReadElementString().Replace("`n","`r`n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to drop `System.Xml.Reader` entirely. PowerShell's built-in XML handling is far easier to manage:

```
[xml]$data = Get-Content "C:\foo.xml"

$data.SelectNodes("//foo") | % {
  $_.bar
  $_.baz
} | Out-File "C:\out.txt"
```

Comment: Under the hood, this is basically a wrapper around the .NET XmlDocument class. I was getting OutOfMemory exceptions when loading my 200 MB, deeply nested files that way.